# Flutter: How to Align multiple ButtonBars such that the radio buttons are one below the other?

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button, alignment, buttonbar

[here you can see what I currently have:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYKUd.png) (I'm currently not allowed to insert this picture).
I have two TabBars with two Radio Buttons each in a ListView, but it looks horrible. I would like to place the radio buttons one below the other, regardless of the length of the strings.

Here is my code:

```dart
 return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        //..
        ),
        Container(
            child: ButtonBar(
          alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // I also tried every other setting here, but none works for me
          children: <Widget>[
            Radio(
              value: 1,
              groupValue: _selectedRadio,
              activeColor: corpColorPrimary,
              onChanged: (val) => setSelectedRadio(val),
            ),
            Text("a long String"),
            Radio(
              value: 2,
              groupValue: _selectedRadio,
              activeColor: corpColorPrimary,
              onChanged: (val) => setSelectedRadio(val),
            ),
            Text("Another long String"),
          ],
        )),

        Container(
          child: ButtonBar(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Radio(
                value: 1,
                groupValue: _selectedRadio,
                activeColor: corpColorPrimary,
                onChanged: (val) => setSelectedRadio(val),
              ),
              Text("Hi"),
              Radio(
                value: 2,
                groupValue: _selectedRadio,
                activeColor: corpColorPrimary,
                onChanged: (val) => setSelectedRadio(val),
              ),
              Text(":)"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Next"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
```

How can I align the Radio buttons correctly?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Spacer(),` widget between each `Container(),` widget and adjust them.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If it works for you can you please share a screenshot?

Comment: please see the answer, i have updated the answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Spacer wigets between the containers will create vertical space and have no effect on the ButtonBar widgets.

Comment: You can also arg value for these functions, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Take Row and in Row take two columns that will solve your issue.